# Failed to compile

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a new component called "counters" but I'm getting this error:

```
./src/components/counters.jsx
Cannot find file: 'Counter.jsx' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\components\counter.jsx'.
```

Comment: rename your file Counter.jsx. or change import '.\src\components\counter.jsx'.

Comment: case is matter. So you should rename it from `Counter.jsx` to `counter.jsx`

Comment: @Ashish thanks a lot. I renamed the file and it worked. Please enlighten me, why it wasn't compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cannot find file: 'Counter.jsx' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\components\counter.jsx'
```

In this error, it is clear that either the file you are trying to import is unavailable or you have misspelled the file name in import.
 Also paths and files are case-sensitive. So the error is in either of the two `Counter.jsx` or `.\src\components\counter.jsx`